# Sprite not adding to scene?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, addchild

I have a strange issue.

In my game, I add a "target to the scene in the first level like so:

```
//Adds the "targets" or in this case falling objects, to the scene and spawns/moves them
-(void)addTarget {
CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bankercatch.png"
                                       rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 21, 40)];

target.tag = 1;

[_targets addObject:target];

// Determine where to spawn the target along the X axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minX = target.contentSize.width/2;
int maxX = winSize.width - target.contentSize.width/2;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;//Randomizes the place it will spawn on X-Axis

// Create the target slightly off-screen along the top edge,
// and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
target.position = ccp(actualX, winSize.height + (target.contentSize.height/2));
[self addChild:target];

// Determine speed of the target
int minDuration = 3.0;
int maxDuration = 5.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;//Speed is randomized between 2 and 5

// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccp(actualX, -target.contentSize.height/2)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
```

This is all fine and good, until I want to make that "target" have an animation as it is falling.  So what I do is create the batchNodes and whatnot in the init

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile: @"DuckSpriteSheet_default.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"DuckSpriteSheet_default.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];
NSMutableArray *fallAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <=4; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"duckling%d.png", i]]];

    }

    CCAnimation *fallAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:fallAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
    self.Duckling = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"duckling1.png"];
    _Duckling.position = ccp(winSize.width*1.5, winSize.height*1.5);
    self.fallAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:fallAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    //[_Banker runAction:_WalkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_Duckling];
```

And then I tried to change my -AddTarget method to look like this:

```
//Adds the "targets" or in this case falling objects, to the scene and spawns/moves them
-(void)addTarget {
//CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bankercatch.png"
//                                       rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 21, 40)];
_Duckling.tag = 1;

[_targets addObject:_Duckling];
[_Duckling runAction:_fallAction];
// Determine where to spawn the target along the X axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minX = _Duckling.contentSize.width/2;
int maxX = winSize.width - _Duckling.contentSize.width/2;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;//Randomizes the place it will spawn on X-Axis
NSLog(@"About to add Duckling to self");
// Create the target slightly off-screen along the top edge,
// and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
_Duckling.position = ccp(actualX, winSize.height + (_Duckling.contentSize.height/2));
[self addChild:_Duckling];//PROBLEM HERE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
NSLog(@"Added _Duckling to self");
// Determine speed of the target
int minDuration = 3.0;
int maxDuration = 5.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;//Speed is randomized between 2 and 5

// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccp(actualX, -_Duckling.contentSize.height/2)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[_Duckling runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
```

I commented in where the Problem is by using NSLogs to find the line.  I get the error

```
Assertion failure in -[DuckL1Layer addChild:z:tag:], /Users/tyler_reynold/Desktop/Programming/Games/Catch It/Catch It/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:388
```

Not on startup, but when AddTarget is run (it runs on a CCScheduleTimer).

Any Ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Show the console output, it will say the type on assertion.

Answer (score 0):

As cocos2d is open-source, you can see actual assert line in it's code. I assume that you tried to add to `self` sprite that is already added to another parent. In this case it is your  `CCSpriteBatchNode` instance. Any CCNode's subclas will cause assertion failure if you try to add it to some parent while it already have parent.

Comment: so then how would i fix the problem @Morion

Comment: I got rid of the [spriteSheet addChild: _Duckling]; in the init, and just did the [self addChild: _Duckling]; in the addTarget method, and it gets all the way through the method (checked by NSLogs) but crashes right after and doesn't add the target.  @Morion

Comment: it is hard to say where is your problem without crash messages

Comment: that's my issue, it doesn't give me an error in the debugger it just crashes

Comment: if it really does not print any crash reason to console, but always crashes, add all-exceptions breakpoint. it will allow you to see the line that is caused crash.

Comment: I probably neglected to mention that I have already done that.  It breaks to the CCActionInterval.m class at the line `if(! [sprite isFrameDisplayed: [frames objectAtIndex: idx]])

Comment: I probably neglected to mention that I have already done that. It breaks to the CCActionInterval.m class at the line `if(! [sprite isFrameDisplayed: [frames objectAtIndex: idx]])